# Can't embed a variable name for a parameter in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

simple question... I am trying to do this:

```
[self.myText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userSizePick]]];
```

So, I am trying to use a variable for the size, but I keep getting an error. Can someone please point out my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: `size` isn't a string parm.

Comment: And if `userSizePick` is a NSString, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userSizePick]` is just wasted motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size argument in `fontWithName:size:` is a `float` as you can see in the method's signature:

```
+ (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize
```

If your `userSizePick` variable is a `NSNumber` you should use:

```
[self.myText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:[userSizePick floatValue]]];
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the obvious, I'll accept after the limit! I just couldn't get it, it was just one of those days

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.myText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:[userSizePick floatValue]];
```

`size:` is a `CGFloat` (`float`) parameter, not an `NSString` parameter. Also, if `userSizePick` is a `NSString`, you don't have to use stringWithFormat:.

Comment: I upvoted you - thanks for the contribution!